Rate of Convergence of Matrix Estimator
Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are iid copies of an $\mathbb R^p$-valued random $X$ with $\operatorname E[\Vert X\Vert^2] < \infty$. Put $\Sigma := \operatorname E[XX']$. A standard estimator for $\Sigma$ is $$\hat\Sigma = \frac 1{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i^{~}X_i'.$$ By Khintchine's Law of Large Numbers, $\hat\Sigma\rightarrow\Sigma$ in probability as $n\rightarrow\infty$. However, this theorem assumes that $p$ is fix, i.e., $p = p_n$ and $p_n\rightarrow\infty$ is not covered. I am looking for a concentration inequality or similar that provides an upper bound to the probability $$P\left(\left\{\Vert\hat\Sigma - \Sigma\Vert>\epsilon\right\}\right)$$ for any $\epsilon>0$ as a function of $n$ and $p$. I want to be as general as possible hence I did not specify the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$, but I am fine with any norm if upper bounds exist for specific norms only. Are there any such upper bounds known?

For these types of results, an absolutely fantastic reference is Joel Tropp's Introduction to Matrix Concentration Inequalities (2015) which, as the title suggests, contains most common matrix concentration inequalities, with detailed proofs and references.
Theorem 1.6.2. there is an extension of the standard Bernstein inequality for random vectors to random matrices, and he happens to discuss in the example 1.6.3. right after how the inequality can be applied to the sample covariance estimator. In particular, if we assume that $\|XX'\|\le B$ almost surely for some $B>0$, we have, using your notations :
$$\mathbb P\left(\left\{\Vert\hat\Sigma - \Sigma\Vert>\epsilon\right\}\right) \le 2p\exp\left(\frac{-n\epsilon^2/2}{B(\mathbb E[\|\Sigma\|]+2\epsilon/3)}\right). $$
(Here $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm)

exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much
